# How to customize Doctrine library in my app to work with Timestamp type

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, timestamp, composer-php

I'm using Composer with Doctrine in my app, but I need to customize the Doctrine code, changing the Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform and Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform classes.

So, I created the MY_AbstractPlatform and  MY_MySqlPlatform classes in the libraries directory of my app and extend the according superclasses. Then I added in my autoload these classes, but nothing happens.

When I write the code of  Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform and Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform classes directly the implementation is carried out sucessfully, but if I implement the methods in the subclasses nothing happens.

I need to customize the Doctrine library, so anyone can help-me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do the customization of modularized way. I managed to create subclasses of Doctrine in my application and use them from the connection setup, setting the driverClass property, instantiating the class my MY_Driver driver.

See how to set up the connection Doctrine, attention for 'driverClass' property:

```
$connection_options = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' => $db['default']['username'],
            'password' => $db['default']['password'],
            'host' => $db['default']['hostname'],
            'dbname' => $db['default']['database'],
            'charset' => $db['default']['char_set'],
            'driverOptions' => array(
                'charset' => $db['default']['char_set'],
            ),
            'driverClass' => new MY_Driver()
        );
```

As my goal was to allow the Doctrine worked with timetamp fields, I created a class to represent the Driver of my application, inheriting the native Driver class. My subclass declares another MY_MySqlPlatform subclass containing customizations for MySql platform to apply the timestamp.

```
class MY_Driver extends Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\Driver {

    /**
     * Define a classe personalizada para o driver da plataforma MySql
     * 
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDatabasePlatform() {

        return new MY_MySqlPlatform();
    }

}
```

The MY_MySqlPlatform class inherits the MySqlPlatform native class, but applying their own methods for using the timestamp type.

```
class MY_MySqlPlatform extends Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getDateTimeTypeDeclarationSQL(array $fieldDeclaration) {
        if (isset($fieldDeclaration['version']) && $fieldDeclaration['version'] == true) {
            return 'TIMESTAMP';
        }

        return 'TIMESTAMP';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getTimestampTypeDeclarationSQL(array $fieldDeclaration) {
        return 'TIMESTAMP';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function initializeDoctrineTypeMappings() {
        $this->doctrineTypeMapping = array(
            'tinyint' => 'boolean',
            'smallint' => 'smallint',
            'mediumint' => 'integer',
            'int' => 'integer',
            'integer' => 'integer',
            'bigint' => 'bigint',
            'tinytext' => 'text',
            'mediumtext' => 'text',
            'longtext' => 'text',
            'text' => 'text',
            'varchar' => 'string',
            'string' => 'string',
            'char' => 'string',
            'date' => 'date',
            'datetime' => 'datetime',
            'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
            'time' => 'time',
            'float' => 'float',
            'double' => 'float',
            'real' => 'float',
            'decimal' => 'decimal',
            'numeric' => 'decimal',
            'year' => 'date',
            'longblob' => 'blob',
            'blob' => 'blob',
            'mediumblob' => 'blob',
            'tinyblob' => 'blob',
            'binary' => 'blob',
            'varbinary' => 'blob',
            'set' => 'simple_array',
        );
    }

}
```

Finally I created a class in my project TimestampType, inheriting the Type native class, to represent an attribute of type Tymestamp during mapping.

```
namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class TimestampType extends Type {

    const TIMESTAMP = 'timestamp';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName() {
        return self::TIMESTAMP;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform) {

        return $platform->getTimestampTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return ($value !== null) ? $value->format($platform->getTimestampTypeDeclarationSQL()) : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        if ($value === null || $value instanceof \DateTime) {
            return $value;
        }

        $val = \DateTime::createFromFormat($platform->getDateTimeFormatString(), $value);
        if (!$val) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailedFormat($value, $this->getName(), $platform->getDateTimeFormatString());
        }

        return $val;
    }

}
```